# Allow Pointer events to bubble from Button clicks

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

What steps to I need to take to enable Pointer events such as PointerPressed and PointerMoved to fire on a Container element when Buttons inside the container are clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I ended up taking was to add event handlers to the container, and set the bool handledEventsToo parameter to true.

```
mainPage.AddHandler(PointerPressedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(pointerPressedHandler), true);
mainPage.AddHandler(PointerMovedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(pointerMovedHandler), true);
```

This means the container still gets a chance to process the events even if they have already been handled.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom button control. Grab the template of a regular button and handle the events yourself - then you will be able to route it.