# Click Button under Border in wp8.1

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

Is it possible to click `Button` which is covered by `Border`?
If it is, how to handle occurred events?

This is page layout:

```
<Page x:Class="App6.MainPage" 
    <!-- ... -->
    >
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="click" />
        <Border Background="Transparent" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The main idea is to catch gesture manipulations (with `Border`) but also allow using controls.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171124/allow-pointer-events-to-bubble-from-button-clicks) I found the way to solve this issue.
Just need to add handler and set parameter `handledEventsToo` in `true`:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Button.AddHandler(PointerPressedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(pointerPressedEvent), true);
}

private void pointerPressedEvent(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

After that  you can see UI callback after clicking the button